# How to merge two users in Mac OS - Catalina?

Tags: user-account, settings

I'm pretty new to Mac Os.
At start I've created a new user, the one that is second in the below picture.
After talking to a co-worker, he told me I probably didn't configure the Mac as company's standard.
So, I decided to change the name to be consistent, and I found this tutorial : https://support.apple.com/el-gr/HT201548.

After changing the name, and restarting my computer I  found out my files are not the same and I thought everything is erased, but it's not.
see the picture below :[image]

I would like to import all my files and configurations from the second user in the picture to the third. is it possible?
(i.e. section 8 in the tutorial didn't go as it should of)

Thanks

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3862590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did actually was to open a 2nd user (also admin), login to the new account and from that account perform the changes.

I changed my account name, my full name but also the home directory. When the OS saw there is no home directory with that name it created a new one.
At the beginning I that all of my data on my user was deleted.
Suddenly I saw the data in home directory and connected what happened.
I accessed the 2nd admin user, changed the name of the home directory to the old one in the pic below, and thats it.

[image]